# Substrate Genesis Configuration newly added pre funded accounts not appearing in polkadotjs/app or in Substrate frontend template

Tags: rust, substrate

In Substrate Node Template Genesis Config I have added a new Account named Golem in ChainSpec local_test_net

```rust
pub fn local_testnet_config() -> Result<ChainSpec, String> {
    let wasm_binary =
        WASM_BINARY.ok_or_else(|| "Development wasm binary not available".to_string())?;

    Ok(ChainSpec::from_genesis(
        // Name
        "Local Testnet",
        // ID
        "local_testnet",
        ChainType::Local,
        move || {
            testnet_genesis(
                wasm_binary,
                // Initial PoA authorities
                vec![
                    authority_keys_from_seed("Alice"),
                    authority_keys_from_seed("Bob"),
                    authority_keys_from_seed("Golem"),
                ],
                // Sudo account
                get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Alice"),
                // Pre-funded accounts
                vec![
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Alice"),
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Bob"),
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Charlie"),
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Dave"),
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Eve"),
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Ferdie"),
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Golem"),
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Alice//stash"),
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Bob//stash"),
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Charlie//stash"),
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Dave//stash"),
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Eve//stash"),
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Ferdie//stash"),
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Golem//stash"),
                ],
                true,
            )
        },
        // Bootnodes
        vec![],
        // Telemetry
        None,
        // Protocol ID
        None,
        // Properties
        None,
        // Extensions
        None,
    ))
}
```

I am running this node as follows

```sh
./target/release/trackback-node \
--chain=local \
--base-path /tmp/validator2 \
--bob \
--node-key=6ce3be907dbcabf20a9a5a60a712b4256a54196000a8ed4050d352bc113f8c58 \
--port 30334 \
--ws-port 9945
```

But when I run the Polkadot JS app or Substrate Front end template, its not appearing

Would like to know how to get it appearing

Comment: Did you build the node after you changed `chain_spec.rs`? This would involve running the command `cargo build --release` or similar.

Comment: @forgetsoYep I did

Comment: I believe that account creation from seed doesn't put "Golem" on the chain, only their public address, once funds are present. Your front end only shows pre-configured account addresses, in this case Alice, Bob, etc.

Comment: When you change the genesis you need to clear the blockchain database. Either delete the folder `/tmp/validator2` or use the `--tmp` argument which always uses a new database.